# What is the default schema in Hive?

Tags: hive

For Pig, the default schema is ByteArray. Is there a default schema for Hive if we don't mention a schema in Hive? I tried to look at some Hive documentation but couldn't find any.

Answer (score 0):

Hive is schema on Read ---   I am not sure this is the answer...If some one could give an insight on this that would be great

> Hive does the best that it can to
>   read the data. You will get lots of null values if there aren’t enough fields in each record
>   to match the schema. If some fields are numbers and Hive encounters nonnumeric
>   strings, it will return nulls for those fields. Above all else, Hive tries to recover from all
>   errors as best it can.

Answer (score 0):

There is not default schema in Hive, in order to query data in hive you have to first create a table explaining the content of your data (by using `create external table ... location`).
So you basically have to tell hive the "scheme" before querying the data.